# Advanced custom field not showing in output

Tags: html, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

This is an excerpt from a modified page.php from Divi. Besides not showing the field content, the h3 tags are not showing up on the page. Shouldn't they be there, regardless of the custom field showing? The site is at: http://vavp.it4causeshosting.org/blog/

```
the_content();

$val = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'spanish_title', true);

echo '<h3>' . $val . '</h3>';

if ( ! $is_page_builder_used )
    wp_link_pages( array(
        'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . esc_html__( 'Pages:', 'Divi' ),
        'after' => '</div>',
    ) );
```

Comment: Actually, you have an empty `<h3>` on line `181` if you look at the page source, right after `<!-- .et_pb_section -->`.

Comment: Just a point about ACF, you should use `get_field('field_name', $post->ID);`. ACF creates an "alias" which sometimes causes problems with `get_post_meta()`. See https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/

Comment: It turns out I misunderstood how Divi handles a blog page. I copied the index.php from the Divi theme to my child theme, then renamed it home.php, and everything worked fine. This also works if you leave the name as index.php, but then any other page that defaults to index.php would also pick up the custom fields.